# Vim airline only works properly when I start a new terminal in an existing terminal

Tags: vim, archlinux, vim-airline

I do not know what does the magic that if I **reopen** another urxvt in an existing urxvt terminal and run vim, vim airline works like a charm, otherwise it displays in a messed status.

Can anyone please give me any suggestion! Thanks a lot.

Comment: if you try: `xrdb ~/.Xresources` inside a urxvt, then launch `vim`, does it work?

Comment: It does not work, but I am really confused about why I start another urxvt instance in the existing urxvt and running vim in the reopened urxvt works.

Comment: To debug, try removing any colorscheme lines from your vimrc. I've seen airline get screwy when there were multiple colorschemes or one doing something funny with setting background.